# creating word documents using laravel but image not load on word file

Tags: laravel, phpword

I am trying to creating a word file using laravel I got success in creating file but I am stuck on only one thing that is adding images to word document. text is load on word file is correct but image is not load.
hear I am attaching my code and html preview image

```
$phpWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();
        $section = $phpWord->addSection();
        $i=1;
         foreach ($que['que'] as $key => $value) {
            if($value['qtype'] == 'text'){
            $text = $section->addText("Q".$i." : ".$value['questions'],array('name'=>'Arial','size' => 12,'bold' => true));}
            else
            {

               $source='http://localhost:81/paper_genrator/storage/app/public/images/'.$value['questions'];
                $text = $section->addImage($source);
            }
            $text = $section->addText(" ");
            $text = $section->addText("A : ".$value['option1']);
            $text = $section->addText("B : ".$value['option2']);
            $text = $section->addText("C : ".$value['option3']);
            $text = $section->addText("D : ".$value['option4']);
             $text = $section->addText(" ");
            $i++;
         }

        $objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'Word2007');
        $objWriter->save($que['que'][0]['cp_name'].'.docx');
```

[image]

Comment: If you put the source url in your browser, does the image appear? Or is `paper_genrator` misspelled for `paper_generator`?

Comment: this is not an issue

Comment: i got the error after trying it. i had post a code is correct but i had done the one mistake i have trying to opened the page in word-pad and word-pad is not supporting the format. after i checked it  in word then it will work perfectly.